# List Not Displaying The Values Only The Name For The Item

Tags: python, python-requests-html

I am working on a little script to pull threads from TheTechGame.com and have it setup so it adds the information to a list but when I loop over that list to display the items in the terminal it just displays the names for the values instead of the title or link.

Code:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get("https://thetechgame.com/Forums/f=4/offtopic-discussion.html")

topic_title = r.html.find("a.topic-title")

topic_list = []

for topic_name in topic_title:
    topic_info = {
        'title': topic_name.text,
        'link': topic_name.absolute_links
    }
    topic_list.append(topic_info)

for items in topic_list:
    print(' '.join(items))
```

Output:

```
title link
title link
...
title link
title link
```

I would like the title for the thread to be displayed `topic_name.text` and the link to show after that `topic_name.absolute_links`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to access the values (instead of the names of the keys, as is currently happening within the `.join()` function). Something like this will give you the output it sounds like you are looking for. Here, you will iterate through each dictionary in the list, then access the values using the `title` key and the `link` key.

```
for t in topic_list:
    print(t['title'], t['link'])
```

This will give you the following output:

```
TheTechGame Special Award Holders + Special Award Tutorials {'https://www.thetechgame.com/Forums/t=7462502/thetechgame-special-award-holders-special-award-tutorials.html'}
TTG All Time High Leaderboard {'https://www.thetechgame.com/Forums/t=7722177/ttg-all-time-high-leaderboard.html'}
...
```

Comment: That seems to work. It is possible to remove the `{' '}` around the link part? Thanks for the answer btw!

Comment: No problem! You could do something like `print(t['title'], t['link'].replace('{', '').replace('}', '') `. This will just replace any instance of those characters with nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it gives me a error `AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'replace'`. I was thinking about using `.strip()` but wouldn't know how to get it to work for what I want to do.

Comment: Ah, my bad. If you convert the link to a string first, and then just include the inner quotes, it should format things correctly. 
`str(t['link']).replace("{\'", "").replace("\'}", "")`

Comment: Thanks man everything works as intended now. Have a great day!